# How to Launch Pervious Tizen app on exit of current Tizen app?

Tags: javascript, tizen, samsung-smart-tv, tizen-web-app, tizen-studio

I have created a Tizen application and when i launch my `Tizen app` from the `Samsung app menu` on `Samsung tv` and after launching when I press `return key` i get back to the `BroadCast menu` instead if `Samsung app menu`.
i am using below code to exit the app after confirmation pop up

```
App.exit = function() {
    if (confirm("Do you want to exit?")) {

        var isRemember = localStorage.getItem('remember');
        console.log("app-rem : " + isRemember);
        if (isRemember == 'false') {
            console.log("cleared");
            localStorage.clear();
            sessionStorage.clear();
        }
        tizen.application.getCurrentApplication().exit();

    }
};
```

**i want  when I launch my application from Samsung app menu and after launching if I exit my app it should open samsung menu instead of broadcasting menu**

Answer (score 2):

You can launch `Samsung app menu` manually by:

```
App.exit = function() {
    if (confirm("Do you want to exit?")) {

        var isRemember = localStorage.getItem('remember');
        console.log("app-rem : " + isRemember);
        if (isRemember == 'false') {
            console.log("cleared");
            localStorage.clear();
            sessionStorage.clear();
        }

        function onsuccess() {
          tizen.application.getCurrentApplication().exit();
        }

        tizen.application.launch("com.samsung.tv.store", onsuccess);

    }
};
```

Also you can try to use below code, but I am not sure that `Samsung app menu` is the caller of your `Tizen app`:

```
var currentApp = tizen.application.getCurrentApplication();
var callerAppId = currentApp.getRequestedAppControl().callerAppId;

function onsuccess() {
    tizen.application.getCurrentApplication().exit();
}

tizen.application.launch(callerAppId, onsuccess);
```

Comment: `callerAppId` is always gettiing `org.tizen.litewebappservice`

Comment: @djus22 Hey this API always gives the same id `org.tizen.litewebappservice`